# Problem with JQuery Mobile and AJAX Post

Tags: jquery, blackberry, jquery-mobile

I'm stumped with this one, for some reason only on Blackberry, I'm not hitting the inner "function" on post.  I'm using the latest JQuery Mobile.  Anyone have an idea?:

```
function test(data1)
    {            
        alert("I do get here!");
        $.post("test.php",
        { data: data1 },
            function(xml) {
                alert("never here!");
            }
        );     
    }
```

Comment: Which version of BlackBerry OS are you testing with?   OS6 uses a webkit browser, so should behave more closely to other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being to change the method to a GET.  I'm not sure why but Blackberry browser doesn't seem to support JQuery POST.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, but only with 5.x OS.
6.0 works fine. For whatever reason the data returned from IIS in my case is causing the post to look like it didn't succeed -- even though it clearly does.

Answer (score 0):

That will only happen `onSuccess`.  Add an `error` handler to see what is going wrong.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that the call isn't resulting in a success and the callback specified for the [`post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) helper method only gets invoked in case of success.  Try either unwrapping the call into a straight [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call or setting the [`ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) or [`ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) callbacks to see if there is an actual issue.

Comment: That helps, but doesn't... it's definitely hitting the error condition, but it's unclear why it only happens on Blackberry.  I'm using ajaxError and it's not showing any error, just undefined exception

Comment: @ry0ohki anything in the XHR responseText or status?.. I would inspect the XHR to see if there is a relevant error (like not a 200 status).

Comment: blank responseText and 0 as status... googling around for 0 status says something about using a submit instead of type=button (this function is called from a submit)

Comment: Try removing data attributes or returning simple text-only content from the server. Also check out if your server side app returns BOM at the beginning - it shouldn't. Finally - see if the server-side is being called at all.